# How to run applications with elevated privilges in Ubuntu using the GUI

Tags: ubuntu, gui, sudo, privileges

Is it possible to launch an application with elevated privilidges using the GUI in Ubuntu 9.04?  Maybe something similar to the right-click / "Run as Administrator" in Windows Vista?

For example, I want to use gedit to modify a system configuration file.  Once I find the file in the File Browser, is there a way to use the GUI to open the file without having to open a terminal and using sudo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alt-F2 to open Ubuntu's equivalent to the Run dialog. Then type `gksudo gedit /path/to/config/file` and hit enter. Alternatively, create a launcher on your desktop or gnome-panel that launches gksudo.

**edit:** [This article](http://maketecheasier.com/ubuntu-easy-and-quick-ways-to-open-any-files-as-root/2008/02/19) says to install `nautilus-gksu` for the right-click open-as-root option.

Comment: *Without* type, using the mouse

Comment: You'll still end up having to type a password, but the article I linked to has mostly-mouseful methods.

Comment: nautilus-gksu was exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is I use it weekly..

search on Tombuntu as I forget the script name..has two options run this APP and Run this app as root

other right click options in the same script are mount media and etc..

Comment: I don't see the script you are writing about.  Could you please share the name if you find it in case others are interested in this topic as well?